# Como importar pacotes dentro de outros sub pacotes no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura em um projeto

```
 PacoteRaiz/
      __init__.py
      Pacote1/
        __init__.py
        Modulo1.py
      Pacote2/
       __init__.py
       Modulo2.py
```

Se eu quiser por exemplo, usar alguma **função que está dentro de Modulo1.py** em **Modulo2.py**, como devo proceder? Eu tentei fazer isso dentro de **Modulo2.py**

`from PacoteRaiz.Pacote1 import Modulo1`

Isso dá erro, "ImportError: No module named PacoteRaiz/Pacote1/Modulo1". Alguém sabe como fazer da forma correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ambos(Pacote1 e Pacote2) estão dentro do mesmo diretório raiz, basta fazer, no Modulo2.py:

```
from Pacote1 import Modulo1
```

para importar o Modulo1.py, ou:

```
from Pacote1.Modulo1 import nomeDaFuncao
```

para importar uma função específica de Modulo1.py.

Comment: Olá! Muito grato por responder! Bom, eu fiz o que vc disse e deu o mesmo erro! Dando uma lida na Internet, eu preciso adicionar no sys.path o diretório aonde está hospedado a aplicação?

Comment: Olá, realmente o que faltava era adicionar ao sys,path os caminhos dos pacotes e a sua resposta ajudou a chegar ao resultado esperado, obrigado!